# Is there anything wrong with this javascript dynamic file include system?

Tags: javascript

CODE:

```
function stop(reason){
    throw(reason);
}
function pragma_once(file_name){
    if(window[file_name] !== undefined)
        stop("Duplicate symbol: "+file_name);
    window["__INCLUDE__"+file_name]=true;
    return true;
}
function include(file_name){
    var x = document.createElement('script');
    x.src = file_name;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(x);
}
```

I've been using node.js and the require() seemed really useful for keeping my code clean, easier to track and easier to read. But as I noticed javascript for web doesn't have "require()". I found requirejs which adds require() functionality to web javascript. But i don't know if using a library is that useful for what seems to be a pretty minor task. So I wrote something that works kind of like like require (more like c #include). The only real problem i noticed is that it loads everything asynchronously. This isn't the final version, but the idea how this functions isn't going to change.

Are there any underlying problems I do not know? Any reason NOT to use this?

Comment: I'd use an existing module bundler, e.g. browserify, webpack or rollup.

Comment: Node.js has `require()` because it's server-side and the act of requiring is a lot more trivial to do when you have the file-system to play with. In the client-side requiring files comes with a lot more complications. I support @FelixKling's suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main reason people tell others not to do this is because of these 3 reasons.

1. It makes another HTTP GET request for this script, and it's not during the initial loading of the page.
2. It is possible to include the same file multiple times from what I've seen.
3. If you need the feature then a more optimized version of that can be found in a web framework or a scripting language that extends Javascript.